# How to retain dropdown selected value after postback javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form in my site. [Fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/riffaz/cznb32ek/)
I removed  tag because it gives error without action.

Here my issue is when I have full form with action, if I click the form its post back the page. Meanwhile the drop down menu show `select an option` :

**before the form is submitted**

[image: before the form is submitted]

**when I select**

[image: When I select]

**After form is submitted**

[image: After form is submitted]

But I want the form should remain the values which is selected before the form is submitted. How can I do that?

Comment: This is a server-side-technology issue. You need to recreate the page with the posted-back values selected. What is your server-side technology?

Comment: you can handle it on server side in asp.net web forms

Comment: @Riffaz Starr - which technology you using for server side scripting ?

Comment: How to find my server side tech? actually this is a Yii framework site..

Comment: Yii is a PHP-based tech. That is your server-side tech. Some PHP guru will suggest how to fix this :)

Answer (score 0):

You could either have the form content dynamically generated on the server-side, and when you submit, you generate the new form with the data already in it.

Or you could resort to ajax instead and don't do form submits.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit your form, it will reload the page. And when the page is reloaded, the select option is by default "select an option". 
You have to store the value before submitting, and when the page is reloaded, check if there is something stored. You can do that with the localStorage for exemple.

Or the second solution is to load the content in ajax, with a webmethod.